# Merging Two Access Databases Stored in Different Locations

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I've searched around for several weeks and I can't find the true answer that I'm looking for. I have two identical Access databases that store file paths. The two databases are stored on two different drives (different locations). I've been trying to find a way to merge the tables without duplicating records. I've incorporated code from the following link:

https://superuser.com/questions/292272/how-do-i-synchronize-multiple-access-databases-together.

The problem occurs when both databases have had added records. The records are added as long as the primary key IDs are not already used. If they are already used it doesn't bother adding the records. Is there a way around this? I can't believe MS Access doesn't have a feature to merge databases. Any help appreciated - thanks

Comment: The best here would be to have only one databse. I tou can't, your database will never be able to share the primary key (if is is an auto incremented one), so that might be a problem.

Comment: Due to multiple office locations, the database needs to be stored on two different drives - one for each location

Comment: Then you should do away with the auto incremented primary key.

Comment: It just sounds like you're asking about merging one table from two different databases. Is the file path field defined with a unique index? You should be able to prebuild append queries with all the fields except the autonumber field.

Comment: Trying to merge all tables but the more important one is my products table. Each record is defined with a unique auto number ID field. The file path field does not have a unique index because some file paths are used more than once for different product numbers.

Answer (score 1):

When appending records you append all fields except the primary key.

The easiest way is to append the records would be to create a linked table n one of the databases.

```
[Table 1]

ID | FilePath | DateCreated |

[Linked Table 1]

ID | FilePath | DateCreated |
```

In this example we select only filepaths from [Linked Table 1] which are not already in Table1 and append them to Table1.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 ( FilePath, DateCreated )
SELECT [Linked Table 1].FilePath, [Linked Table 1].DateCreated
FROM [Linked Table 1]
WHERE ((([Linked Table 1].FilePath) Not In (Select FilePath FROM Table1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a macro that overwrites one of the databases, effectively having a master database and a backup?

```
Save = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
(FileFilter:="Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
```

Use this code in a macro and then assign that macro to a button.

Im not 100% sure of how to choose specifically where the save menu goes first (i.e. a default search location), as I have only been looking at VBA for just over a week. But as long as you have access to both locations then this should be easily done!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

An extremely simple method is to have a third database for the purpose.

In this, link the the two tables from the two databases.

Then create a query to retrieve the data:

```
Select TableA.* From TableA
Union
Select TableB.* From TableB
```

This will return the unique records combined from the two tables.